# Difference between genometools installed with anaconda vs apt-get?

Tags: bioconda

I installed genometools with anaconda `conda install -c bioconda genometools`. Something is installed though apparently no binary called `gt`. If I type in gt Ubuntu suggests to install genometools via `apt`. What is the difference between both versions? Why is there no `gt` binary in the anaconda package?

Answer (score 7):

These appear to be two separate collections of tools. The conda version is a collection of python scripts whereas the apt version is based on a C library. So, as you might expect, the python version does not have a `gt` binary.

They also have separate GitHub accounts [conda genometools](https://github.com/flo-compbio/genometools) vs [apt genometools](https://github.com/genometools/genometools).