# How to install genometools with anaconda?

Tags: genometools

I tied to install genometools with anaconda:

```
conda install -c bioconda genometools
```

Though, after running that successfully the command `gt` is not available in my conda environment.

> The program 'gt' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing: sudo apt install genometools

While conda tells me the program is installed. Are there multiple packages called genometools? What is the difference and can I install the package providing `gt` with anaconda at all? There is also a package called `genometools-genometools`, but it only has two downloads. So, I am not sure that is what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between genometools installed with anaconda vs apt-get?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5513/difference-between-genometools-installed-with-anaconda-vs-apt-get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`genometools-genometools` seem to be the current version. By installing the `genometools` package I received the same error like you. I guess it's because the binary isn't copy to `bin` during installation.

`genometools-genometools` seems to work fine. And it has `2k` (2000) and not `2` :)

Comment: Maybe I was looking at the wrong channel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

genometools-genometools worked for me, while 2 other options (genometools and -c leylabmpi genometools) did not.

Comment: Hi thanks Sara could you clarify your installation code please?  it appears you are designating channnels within Anaconda

Comment: Hi Michael, the example with the channel specified was a "fix" that was suggested elsewhere. What worked for me was "conda install -n GT genometools-genometools" where I specified the environment I wanted to install in (GT) but not the channel to use.